# Is there a way to extract inline CSS into a CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have many html pages with loads of css within  the style attribute. i am wondering if there is a way to replace all that with css classes automatically?

Are there a plugin for Eclipse or any third party programs?

edit:

I found [this](http://inlinecssextractor.com/home.html) but I don't like how it uses these kinds of selectors because its hard to figure out what they're referencing:

```
#addDiv > TABLE:nth-child(1) > TBODY:nth-child(4) > TR:nth-child(1) > TD:nth-child(4){width: 100%}
```

Comment: I've never heard of anything that can do this and I would find it very difficult to believe a program would be able to do it well.  I can see all kinds issues with the program thinking it could combine certain things into one class for several elements and not combining things when it should.

Comment: Assuming that you mean there are a lot of inline styles (what a pain!) then I've never seen anything like this before. As with the above comment a program that could do this, would likely just combine styles together and create a mess!

Answer (score 0):

CSS offers structure that no inline-styling can ever get. Unless you'd like a messy stylesheet and every element in your html with an id, there is no other alternative than do to it by hand.

Generated:

```
#id3255 { /* styling */ }
#id4325 { /* styling */ }
```

Manual

```
#wrapper { /* styling */ }
#wrapper p { /* styling for paragraphs in your wrapper */ }
```

Not to say you cannot copy inline styles to a css, though most proper browsers and editing programs can read out the inline styles for copy-pasting.

Comment: Inline styling is also hell to maintain!